# Moment determinacy of joint distribution implies moment determinacy of projection

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X$ be an $n$-dimensional random vector with a distribution $P$ that is uniquely characterized by its moments. Consider the scalar random variable $\xi_1 X_1 + \dots \xi_n X_n$ with a vector $\xi \in \mathbb R^n$.

Is the distribution of the scalar random variable then also determined uniquely by its own moments?